# Excel formula for a "running %" of a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

im trying to figure a formula for a running percentage of entries in a column.
For example, in column A, i have "r" for returns, and "n" for non returns, and "c" for canceled, but "c" is classed as a non return.
As i enter the value, i'd like a "live" % of the overall column as i enter it:
I have used =IF(B3="r",SUM(G2+1),SUM(G2-1)) but that doesnt give me a percentage! Thanks.

Comment: @gtwebb, thanks heaps, worked just as i needed, and your assumtion about headers in row 1 was spot on. Sorry this comment is late, i think we are on a different time zone. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @rchen, thanks for the extra info, i didnt want the final values large as you pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this formula in cell G2 (assuming you have headers in row 1).

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,"r")/COUNTA($A$2:A2)
```

Format it as a percentage (ctrl+shift+5) and copy it down.  It could potentially slow down with enough rows but I prefer not to use reliance on the row above if I don't need too (depends on the size of the worksheet).

Answer (score 0):

You shall format the percentage column as percentage, you may click on percentage symbol, on top of excel program or you can click with right button, format and select percentage. If the final value is to high (10000% per exemple), maybe you should divide per 100 to show the correct value.